# HSTS header missing error even its show in application with preload (and http port also disable)

Tags: weblogic, web.xml, hsts, val

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iTJ5.png)

I have issue with application show HSTS header missing val but I already fix this
added HSTSFILER java and mapped with web.xml too but
when during scan it's still show HSTS header is missing.
I am able to see HSTS header in application in response header as image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
   throws IOException, ServletException {
  HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;

  if (req.isSecure())
   resp.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31622400; includeSubDomains");

  chain.doFilter(req, resp);
 }    this is code in HSTSFilter class

Comment: and mapped with web.xml              filter>
574       <filter-name>HSTSFilter</filter-name>
575       <filter-class>packagepath.HSTSFilter</filter-class>
576       <init-param>
577         <param-name>host</param-name>
578         <param-value>servername</param-value>
579       </init-param>
580   </filter>
581   <filter-mapping>
582      <filter-name>HSTSFilter</filter-name>
583      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
584   </filter-mapping>